# php session.upload_progress with multiple files using an array for input names

Tags: php, html

I'm having an issue with using the session.upload_progress method to create individual upload progress bars for each upload. For my multiple file uploads I'm using an array as the name and giving the user the ability to have multiple file inputs in one input or multiple file inputs.

Example:

```
<input type='file' name='files[]' multiple='true'/>
<input type='file' name='files[]' multiple='true'/>
```

The upload works fine but when I send an AJAX request to another file to get the upload progress it only sends back the overall progress and the progress of the first file being uploaded.  The overall progress shows that there are a lot more files being uploaded and yet only one is shown in the upload progress array.

The file that sends back the upload progress looks like

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
session_start();

$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . "imageform";

if (!empty($_SESSION[$key])) {
    echo json_encode($_SESSION[$key]);
    exit;
}
exit;
```

So when I get this back I'm only getting the overall progress and the first file in the upload queue. I did notice though that the name of the input field given in the array for that file is "files[]".  I'm wondering if it must have unique input name fields in order to differentiate between the separate files or not.

I have searched the web for solutions to this but the only implementations of the session.upload_progress I have found have different names for each file input and so I haven't been able to find any that explain how to do it this way or if it's even possible to get all the individual files this way.

Thanks in advance for any help or direction.

Comment: I suspect this is due to a single POST event happening when the form is submitted. The POST headers contain all the data from the form all at once. You may want to build out a loop that uploads each file directly, maybe via AJAX, and this way, when the first completes, the next begins as a new POST event.